# Where does my proof of Milman-Pettis theorem break down?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology, reflexive-space

I'm trying to prove Milman-Pettis's theorem.

> Let $E$ be a uniformly convex Banach space. Then $E$ is reflexive.

Clearly, my attempt is not correct because I have not used the uniform convexity of $E$. Could you elaborate on where my logic fails?

---

Let denote by $E_w$ the set $E$ together with the weak topology $\sigma(E, E')$. Let denote $E''_w$ the set $E''$ together with the weak$^\star$ topology $\sigma(E'', E')$. Let $J:E_w \to E''_w, x \mapsto \hat x$ be the canonical injection. Then $J$ when restricted to its image is a homeomorphism which sends open/close/compact set to open/close/compact set.

By Kakutani's theorem, it's enough to prove that $B_E:= \{x\in E \mid |x| \le 1\}$ is compact in $\sigma(E, E')$. Because $J$ (restricted to its image) is a homeomorphism, it suffices to show that $J[B_E]$ is compact in the weak$^\star$ topology $\sigma(E'', E')$. By Banach–Alaoglu theorem, $B_{E''} := \{\varphi \in E'' \mid \| \varphi \| \le 1\}$ is compact in $\sigma(E'', E')$. Clearly, $J[B_E] \subseteq B_{E''}$, so it suffices to show that $J[B_E]$ is closed in $\sigma(E'', E')$. However, this is true because $B_E$ is closed in $\sigma(E, E')$ and $J$ (restricted to its image) is a homeomorphism.

---

**Update:** I added a proof that $J$ (restricted to its image) is a homeomorphism.

Let $F:= J[E]$. We denote by $F_w$ the set $F$ with the subspace topology $\tau$ that $\sigma(E'', E')$ induces on $F$. Let's prove that $J:E_w \to F_w$ is a homeomorphism. Clearly, $J$ is bijective.

> *Lemma:* Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space, $A \subseteq X$, and $\tau_A$ the subspace topology of $A$. Let $a\in A$ and $(x_d)_{d \in D}$ is a net in $A$. Then $x_d \to a$ in $\tau$ if and only if $x_d \to a$ in $\tau_A$.

Let $x,x_d\in E$. To prove that $J, J^{-1}$ are continuous, we need to prove that $x_d \to x$ in $\sigma(E, E')$ if and only if $\hat x_d \to \hat x$ in $\tau$. By our *Lemma*, we need to prove $x_d \to x$ in $\sigma(E, E')$ *if and only if* $\hat x_d \to \hat x$ in $\sigma(E'', E')$. This equivalence is indeed true because

- $\hat x_d \to \hat x$ in $\tau$ if and only if $f(x_d) \to f(x)$ for all $f\in E'$.
- $\hat x_d \to \hat x$ in $\sigma(E'', E')$ if and only if $\hat x_d (f) \to \hat x (f)$ for all $f\in E'$ if and only if $f(x_d) \to f(x)$ for all $f\in E'$.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. Maybe you need reflexiv to establish the properties of $J$? How would you show that it is a homeo onto its image? Injective and continuous is fine, but how do we get the continuity of the inverse?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I've just updated my question with the proof that $J$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f\in X\to Y$ be a homeomorphism and $Y\subseteq Z$.  If $S\subseteq X$ is closed, then $f(S)$ is closed in $Y$, since $f$ is a homeomorphism.  But it need not be closed in $Z$.  For example, take $X=Y=(-1,1)$, $f$ is the identity, and $Z=[-1,1]$; then $X$ is closed in $X$, but its image is not closed in $Z$.

You want to show $J(B_E)$ closed in $E_w''$, not in $\operatorname{im}{J}$.  But you only show the latter.